# Merging two Python dictionaries but remaining the order

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I want to merge two dictionaries but the order doesn't need to change. Dictionary 2 needs to be "pasted" behind Dictionary 1. (or vice versa)

```
d1 = {'a': 100, 'b': 200}
d2 = {'x': 300, 'y': 200}
d3 = ?
print d3
>>> {'x': 300, 'y': 200, 'a': 100, 'b': 200}
```

I tried using the python3 way of combining dictionaries:

```
d1 = {'a': 100, 'b': 200}
d2 = {'x': 300, 'y': 200}
d3 = {**d1, **d2}
print(d3)
>>> {'y': 200, 'b': 200, 'a': 100, 'x': 300}
```

But the order is not remained. Any help?

Comment: Briefly: the order doesn't remain because it was never there in the first place. Dictionaries are arbitrarily ordered. If order matters, you will need to use a different class, like `OrderedDict`, as shown in the linked question's answers.

Comment: Wait a while for Python 3.6; Python 3.6 **will retain the ordering of dictionary**.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala - I'm not sure whether that will be enough to replace `OrderedDict`, as [the changelist](https://docs.python.org/3.6/whatsnew/3.6.html) says that it's specifically for maintaining the order of `**kwargs` (i.e., for the `dict()` constructor), so it might not apply to literals. It also says that this is currently an implementation detail that shouldn't be relied upon.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I've tested it, it applies to every single dictionary, including updates and so on. Yes, it is currently an implementation detail though. But it also works for this one.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3: insertion order is maintained. Literals are processed from left to right, so `{'a': 1: 'b': 2}` places `'a'` first. There is a long-standing bug that in dictionaries displays, the value expression is evaluated before the key expression, but key-value pairs retain their order in 3.6.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala and Martijn - thanks, I will keep that in mind.